# Webkit autofill doesn't work on my website

Tags: html, webkit

So, I have an a website, which works fine, but my login form doesn't offer to autofill credentials.

```html
<form action="{{ path('security_check') }}" method="post">
   <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="username">{{ 'label.username'|trans }}</label>
         <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" class="form-control"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="password">{{ 'label.password'|trans }}</label>
         <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <span style="color: white" class="js-active" id="password-recovery">Я забыл пароль</span>
      </div>
      <label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="_remember_me" checked>
                                        Запомнить меня
      </label>
         <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="_failure_path" value="{{ path('security_failure') }}"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ path('security_success') }}"/>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

In others websites Safari, in my case, offers to autocomplete saved username&password. But on my site that functionality not appear.

My WebSite:
[image: My Site]
Other WebSite
[image: Other WebSite]
Where is the problem?

UPD: Plain HTML of Login Modal Form:

```html
<div class="modal fade show" id="formLoginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="formLoginModalLabel" style="display: block; padding-left: 0px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" style="background-color: rgba(133, 129, 139, 0.49); -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(4px); backdrop-filter: blur(4px); border-radius: 25px; color: white;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="formLoginModalLabel">Авторизация</h5>
                <button style="color: white; margin: -0.75rem -1rem -1rem auto;" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form action="/security_check" method="post">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="well">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="username">Логин</label>
                                            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" class="form-control" autocomplete="username">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="password">Пароль</label>
                                            <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <span style="color: white" class="js-active" id="password-recovery">Я забыл пароль</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="_remember_me" checked="">
                                            Запомнить меня
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="_failure_path">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path">
                                    </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light form-submit">Войти</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could try if adding the [autocomplete attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) helps.

Comment: I’ve tried add autocomplete on inputs, it doesn’t help. Or what do you mean?

Comment: You add `autocomplete="username"` to the user name input and `autocomplete="current-password"` to the password input. Note that your form is missing a submit button, which is needed for this to work.

Comment: submit button must be inside the form?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob Wasn't it [required in XHTML](https://jakearchibald.com/2023/against-self-closing-tags-in-html/)? The thing before HTML5.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes it is but XHTML is not HTML. XHTML is XML

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, I added submit button to the form, and added `autocomplete`, but there is no changes. I can upload updated form

Comment: There's no answer to your question yet, so I guess changing it doesn't matter all that much. If you do, please copy the plain HTML source from your browser, we can't work with your template inserts.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I added HTML source of login modal.

Comment: Well, there's still no submit button in the form.

Comment: And in addition, `autocomplete` only offers what I had in saved data, but I need data from my passwords, saved on device, as described on second screenshot

Comment: Try changing `<button type="button">Войти</button>` to `<button type="submit" form="formLoginModal">Войти</button>`. I left out the classes for clarity. You will likely also have to handle the extra submit event in Javascript with [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Comment: Sorry, you lost me with that last comment. I'm not sure what we're talking about here anymore.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. Still no autocomplete.

Comment: "**Sorry, you lost me with that last comment. I'm not sure what we're talking about here anymore.**"

let me explain: when i open a login modal, I want to be asked about saved passwords on my device, which is belongs to this webSite, like on second uploaded screenshot, but I do not asked for saved data on my own webSite.

Comment: OK, yes, that's what I thought you meant. Anyway, I'm out of ideas. The only thing I thought of was that it might not work when you run your website locally, without a domain. But I cannot find any reference about that in relation to password saving.